# How to Json decode multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$json = <<<'JSON'
{
   "statuscode":"TXN",
   "status":"Transaction Successful",
   "data":{
      "item":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "zone":"S",
            "state_alias":"AP",
            "state":"ANDHRA PRADESH",
            "is_active":"1"
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "zone":"E",
            "state_alias":"AR",
            "state":"ARUNACHAL PRADESH",
            "is_active":"1"
         },
         {
            "id":"3",
            "zone":"E",
            "state_alias":"AS",
            "state":"ASSAM",
            "is_active":"1"
         },
         {
            "id":"4",
            "zone":"E",
            "state_alias":"BR",
            "state":"BIHAR",
            "is_active":"1"
         },
         {
            "id":"5",
            "zone":"W",
            "state_alias":"CG",
            "state":"CHHATTISGARH",
            "is_active":"1"
         },
         {
            "id":"6",
            "zone":"W",
            "state_alias":"GA",
            "state":"GOA",
            "is_active":"1"
         }
      ]
   }
}
JSON;

$json_data  = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($json_data['data'] as $r){

    foreach($r['item'] as $data){

       echo $data->id;

    }               

}
```

I need to list out all the states in loop.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/oQaJf

Comment: Use only one foreach. Modify your foreach by this code

```foreach($json_data['data']['item'] as $data){
  echo $data['id'];
}```

Comment: thank you #Nick & #Abdullah Al Mamun .

Comment: Problem sloved??

Comment: ya  bro thanks , please check this one same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57950546/how-decode-3-dimensional-array